# SSMS 2016 Job Schedule Wizard Starting At entry field

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-agent, sql-server-2016

I am using SSMS 2016. In the wizard for job schedules the field for Starting/Ending At shows only one character, and is unusable. Here is the screen shot.

[image: SSMS2016]

SSMS version should be the latest at 13.0.16000.28.

Anyone else see or experience this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This only occurs for me when the text size of my screen has been set to Medium or Large, or when the window is misalgined and needs to be minimized and maximized again. [image]

Comment: Ah, that worked. Thanks. Now I have to squint at everything else. :)